# Reload a directive, to iterate over the elements that use it. in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that validates all the fields of a form that contain the "validate" directive. In all fields the word "logan" must exist to be correct. At any given time I want and need, when I click on the "Re_Evaluate all the form" button, validate if the form is correct, iterating in all the elements of the form, just like when the $timeout function is executed the first time .

```
    app.directive('validate', function ($timeout,$compile) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }   

          $timeout(function() {

              console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);  //I need this, iterate in all elements with the directive 'validate', when   re_evaluate() is clicked      
              if(ngModel.$viewValue=='logan'){
                ngModel.$setValidity('validate',true);
              }
              else{
                ngModel.$setValidity('validate',false);
              }

            })

          scope.re_evaluate = function(){
            console.log('I need re-evaluate all the form!')
          } 

          }

        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmk0yg42/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is

```
<section ng-app="app">
    <article ng-controller="appCtrl" class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal well" name="zform" invalidate>
         <input type="text" name="mytext1"  ng-model="my_text"  validate />
         <input type="text" name="mytext2" ng-model="my_text2"  validate />
         <input type="text" name="mytext3"  ng-model="my_text3"  validate />
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="zform.$invalid">
                Validate</button>

        </form>
    </article>
</section>
```

And the JS is

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.my_text='logan';
$scope.my_text2 = 'logan';
$scope.my_text3 = 'logan';

});

app.directive('validate', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {


          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
            var valid = value == 'logan';
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('logan',valid);
             return value;
          });


          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
             var valid = value == 'logan';
             ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('logan', valid);
             return value;
          });

    }
    };
});
```

you don't need a re-evaluate button